# The provided key element does not match the schema in AWS-DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS. So I working on a learning project, in which I am facing issue to update the user details using node.js. This is my code. In this code I am getting error :  The provided key element does not match the schema. please help me to solve this error.

```
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const {
  DynamoDBDocumentClient,
  UpdateCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    if (!event.queryStringParameters || !event.queryStringParameters.email) {
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: "Email parameter is missing.",
      };
    }

    const email = event.queryStringParameters.email;
    const name = event.name;

    const command = new UpdateCommand({
      TableName: "users",
      Key: {
        email: email,
      },
      UpdateExpression: "set #attr1 = :val1",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#attr1": "name",
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":val1": name,
      },
      ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
    });
    const data = await docClient.send(command);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: "User updated successfully" + data,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: "Error updating user: " + error.message,
    };
  }
};
```

Below is my .yml file of table scheme:

```
users:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: users
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: email
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: name
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: email
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: name
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Below is my Input:

```
{
  "queryStringParameters": {
      "email": "testing1@gmail.com"
  },
  "name": "Shivam Dubey"
}
```

I tried with full of my capacity but I did not find the solution. I tried the solution from official documentation and also take help from chatGPT but no improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is update the sort key value of your item, which is `name`. DynamoDB prohibits you from updating a sort key. I would suggest you do one of two things:

1. Create a table without a sort key, this will allow your current approach to work as expected.
2. If you require the sort key `name` for uniqueness, then you must use a `PutItem` and add a new item to the table for each `email` + `name` combination.

Comment: Thanks for response Mr. Lee. That error has removed but new error has shown that is --- ''userCrud-dev-updateUser is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource "---" because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:PutItem action."

Comment: Action:
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - dynamodb:Scan
      Resource: my_resource

Comment: This is my .yml file for action permission.

Comment: Can you share the policy from the web console for this user, add it to your question in JSON format.

Comment: And if this is the actual error: 'userCrud-dev-updateUser is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource "---" because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:PutItem action."

Then you have tried to put an item to a table called `---` instead of `users`

Comment: This is my policy json file link https://codeshare.io/N38j94

Comment: Yes, but that is not your lambdas execution role I'm guessing.

Comment: This is my whole .yml file https://codeshare.io/dwPAo4